# Error generated in the snippet to upload files to google appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, blobstore

The following snippet generates an error in the IDE and when I click to deploy the application.

```
        <form  action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" name="myFile"/>
          <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Errors :

```
error: cannot find symbol
[javac]       out.print( blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") );
[javac]                  ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable blobstoreService
[javac]   location: class UploadTester_jsp
[javac] 1 error
```

What do I need to add  ? Why do I get this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare and then initialize variable `blobstoreService`.

```
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService" %>
....

<%
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
%>
```

Above is directly from [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview).

Comment: can you please tell what does _/upload_ mean in : `blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload")`

Comment: As it is said in documentation ( https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService#createUploadUrl%28java.lang.String%29 ): "A relative URL which will be invoked after the user successfully uploads a blob. Must start with a "/""